# Python pandas rolling computations with custom step size

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a pandas dataframe with **daily** data. At the last day of each **month**, I would like to compute a quantity that depends on the **daily** data of the previous *n* months (e.g., n=3).

My current solution is to use the [pandas rolling function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to compute this quantity for every day, and then, only keep the quantities of the last days of each month (and discard all the other quantities). This however implies that I perform a lot of unnecessary computations.

Does somebody of you know how I can improve that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**
In the following, I add two examples. In both cases, I compute rolling regressions of stock returns. The first (short) example shows the problem described above and is a sub-problem of my actual problem. The second (long) example shows my actual problem. Therefore, I would either need a solution of the first example that can be embedded in my algorithm for solving the second example or a completely different solution of the second example. Note: The dataframe that I'm using is very large, which means that multiple copies of the entire dataframe are not feasible.

Example 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Generate a time index
dates = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=365, freq="D", name='date')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates,columns=['Y','X']).sort_index()

# Generate Data
df['X'] = np.array(range(0,365))
df['Y'] = 3.1*X-2.5
df = df.iloc[random.sample(range(365),280)] # some days are missing
df.iloc[random.sample(range(280),20),0] = np.nan # some observations are missing
df = df.sort_index()
# Compute Beta
def estimate_beta(ser):
    return sm.OLS(df.loc[ser.index,'Y'], sm.add_constant(df.loc[ser.index,'X']), missing = 'drop').fit().params[-1]     
df['beta'] = df['Y'].rolling('60D', min_periods=10).apply(estimate_beta) # use last 60 days and require at least 10 observations

#  Get last entries per month
df_monthly = df[['beta']].groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M', level='date')]).agg('last')
df_monthly
```

Example 2:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import IndexSlice as idx
import random
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Generate a time index
dates = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=365, freq="D", name='date')
arrays = [dates.tolist()+dates.tolist(),["10000"]*365+["10001"]*365]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)), names=["Date", "Stock"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=['Y','X']).sort_index()

# Generate Data
df.loc[idx[:,"10000"],'X'] = X = np.array(range(0,365)).astype(float)
df.loc[idx[:,"10000"],'Y'] = 3*X-2
df.loc[idx[:,"10001"],'X'] = X
df.loc[idx[:,"10001"],'Y'] = -X+1
df = df.iloc[random.sample(range(365*2),360*2)] # some days are missing
df.iloc[random.sample(range(280*2),20*2),0] = np.nan # some observations are missing

# Estimate beta
def estimate_beta_grouped(df_in):
    def estimate_beta(ser):
        return sm.OLS(df.loc[ser.index,'Y'].astype(float),sm.add_constant(df.loc[ser.index,'X'].astype(float)), missing = 'drop').fit().params[-1]
    df = df_in.droplevel('Stock').reset_index().set_index(['Date']).sort_index()
    df['beta'] = df['Y'].rolling('60D',min_periods=10).apply(estimate_beta)
    return df[['beta']]
df_beta = df.groupby(level='Stock').apply(estimate_beta_grouped)

# Extract beta at last day per month
df_monthly = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M', level='Date'), df.index.get_level_values(1)]).agg('last') # get last observations
df_monthly = df_monthly.merge(df_beta, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left') # merge beta on df_monthly
df_monthly
```

Comment: can you give an example of the data and the wanted results?